# How to decide whether to install fresh or upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade

I can't seem to find any resources that discuss how to decide whether to upgrade to 18.04 or do a fresh install.  All articles I have found either discuss only how to upgrade, or provide a "one-size-fits-all" opinion about which is better.

To clarify: I am not asking for a specific answer based on my current version and hardware (which is why I have not included it here); I am looking to understand what criteria are important to consider.  I know that current version, as well as upgrade history, are important, and so is hardware compatibility.  But I assume that there are also other criteria that should factor in.

I am hoping to find something along the lines of a checklist that defines  generally agreed-upon criteria that is necessary to consider when making a decision about whether to upgrade or install fresh.

Is there any such thing?

TIA.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think you can upgrade to 18.04LTS until 18.04.1 is released (which will be happening soon).  Many of us are doing fresh installs of 18.04 LTS to test it prior to deploying it globally as an upgrade.  Perhaps I am missing something here, but the main decision concerning upgrading versus doing a clean install is whether you care about losing the files, configurations, customizations, user setups and so on that are in the current build you are running on.  You'll also need to do some reading... 18.04 is only upgradeable from a limited number of older versions.

Comment: IMO, the most important thing to consider is a separate home partition. That enables you to install whichever Ubuntu version you like without the hassle to copy your files back and forth. And an Ubuntu installation takes ~5-10 minutes.